# How to start Worklight server automatically deployed in Websphere Liberty Core

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I can start the server with below command in Window

```
..\bin\server start <server_name>
```

but the server will be closed right after I quit the cmd window, do we have anyway to start the server without being required to remain the CMD window open? and start upon system boot up?

Comment: Can this question be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

This is APAR [PM86632](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM86632), which was resolved in 8.5.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

IBM Worklight does not provide such a tool; this should be the responsibility of the hosting application server. In case it is not provided by it, it should be pretty much a generic action to create IMO.

Try perhaps to follow up on the instructions in these websites for how to create a service. The service will need to run the command that starts the server:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106742/Creating-a-simple-Windows-Service
- http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1401-startup-programs-change.html